# How many faces can my computer handle?

Tags: faces

I have a macbook running MacOs High Sierra vs 10.13.6 with this processor: 2.3GHz Intel Core i5, and this amount of memory: 8 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3, and this graphics card: Intel Iris Plus Graphics 640 1536 MB. I would really like to know how many faces my computer can handle without blender crashing. I am wanting to import a mesh that has 7 million faces, is this ok to do?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

I have no clue. However, you can make a sphere in a new blender project and subdivide the surface untill the app starts to lag. Then, you can apply the modifier and read the face count in the top toolbar. That should give you an approximation.